# Why can't I determine the path for require.context in a karma shim by passing a variable?

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, require

I want to set the path for require.context(path, ...) in a shim file called by karma (set in the files parameter in the config) dynamically, but somehow, as soon as I use a variable for path, I get the error 'Cannot find module "."' in the CLI. This is very odd, because if I hardcode the *very same* path into the call, it runs without a problem. Aka, if I do

```
var testPath = '../src';
console.log("PATH 2 " + testPath); // ../src
var appContext = require.context(testPath, true, /\.spec\.ts/);
```

I'll get an error, if I do

```
var appContext = require.context('../src', true, /\.spec\.ts/);
```

everything is fine.

In the full shim file the code appears exactly as I have written it here, aka there is no other code between the definition of testPath and require.context, I just included the console.log to check for some inexplicable voodoo.

The shim is invoked as follows in the karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  var _config = {
    .....
    files: [
      {pattern: './karma-test-shim.js', watched: true}
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './karma-test-shim.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },
    .....
  };
  config.set(_config);
};
```

What am I missing? Does the call to the same shim by preprocessors mess things up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack does not support passing parameters other than literals to `require.context`. The [reason](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4772#issuecomment-296798125) given by the project owner on github is:

> It must be statically analyzable...

It would be possible in theory to do a dynamic analysis of this:

```
var testPath = '../src';
console.log("PATH 2 " + testPath); // ../src
var appContext = require.context(testPath, true, /\.spec\.ts/);
```

and discover that the first parameter to `require.context` is `../src`. However, it gets more complicated when you have things like:

```
// If in browser use "foo", otherwise use "bar". (The test has been
// simplified as it is not our focus here.)
var testPath = (typeof window !== "undefined") ? "foo" : "bar";
var appContext = require.context(testPath, true, /\.spec\.ts/);
```

The code above cannot be meaningfully resolved by Webpack. Whether or not you are in a browser is a run time condition but Webpack is performing its analysis at build time, not at run time. Enabling dynamic analysis, besides the significant cost it would have, would still not work for a lot of use-case scenarios.

Comment: well, I am just trying to limit karma to one particular spec file passed in the CLI, instead of rerunning all tests when I want to concentrate on just that one test, but I guess I'll have to find another way that does not involve webpack... :-S

Comment: Limit tests that are run by prefixing those tests with "f", or to exclude using "x".  example fdescribe(...) will run only that test group, while xdescribe(...) will exclude that test group.  You can also use those prefixes on the it function.