# TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function - Works hardcoded but not with parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

```
const importAll = (r) => r.keys().map(r);
const importAllFrom = (dir) => importAll(require.context(dir, false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/))
```

Calling `importAllFrom("../images") throws an error 'webpack_require__(...).context is not a function'.

However the following code where I hardcode the directory name works just fine.

```
const importAll = (r) => r.keys().map(r);
const importAllFrom = (dir) => importAll(require.context("../images", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/))
```

All the code is in the same react component.

Am I missing something really silly??

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458809/why-cant-i-determine-the-path-for-require-context-in-a-karma-shim-by-passing-a

Comment: Ah brilliant, at least it's not something stupid in my javascript!

Answer (score 4):

It didn't actually cross my mind to check the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/) for this problem because 99% of the time this sort of problem is a typo but actually they state that this is how it's supposed to work:

> The arguments passed to require.context must be literals!